# Guassian or pseudo-Gaussian integrals: Applications in $\text{QFT}.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In $\text{QFT},$ we use "harmonic approximations" very often such that we end up integrating variations of

$$  I_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!dx\, e^{-x^2} .$$

I am finding all the variations I need to solve in tables of Gaussian and pseudo-Gaussian integrals.  However, physical situations have "anharmonic" terms and we encounter variations of

$$  I_4=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!dx\, e^{-x^4} .$$

I can't solve this one or find the answer.  Is this integral known in closed form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \: e^{-x^4} = 2 \int_0^\infty dx \: e^{-x^4} = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty dt \: t^{-\frac{3}{4}}e^{-t} = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

but this can be a little unsatisfying. One interesting fact though is that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_{2n} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \: e^{-x^{2n}} = \int_{-1}^1 dx = 2$$

omitting the odd terms since they all diverge. This is a monotonically increasing sequence, and we can bound all $I_{2n}$ by

$$\sqrt{\pi} \leq I_{2n} \leq 2$$

with $2$ being a very good approximation for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Ninad Munshi's answer
$$I_{2n} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-x^{2n}}\,dx = 2\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2 n+1}{2 n}\right)$$ and, for large values of $n$
$$I_{2n} =2-\frac{\gamma }{n}+\frac{6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: This is quite a beautiful expansion, I'm saving it for later!

Answer (score 0):

With substitution $x^4=u$ we see
$$I_4=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}\frac14u^{-\dfrac34}du$$
gives you a term of Gamma integral